# delete an existing file in grails

Tags: grails, file-upload, file-io, grails-2.0

I am saving image files in my web folder. But at the time of saving or suppose a user want to change his picture than i want to delete the old picture and save the new one with the same file name. But I am failing after trying. Can anyone please help me on this please? Here is all my action below :

my save action >>>

```
    def savePicture = {
        String message = ""
        def user = User.findById(1)
        def userId = user.id
        MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
        CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("productPic");

        def okcontents = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif']
        if (! okcontents.contains(f.getContentType())) {
            message = "Avatar must be one of: ${okcontents}"
            render(view:'uploadForm', model:[message: message])
            return;
        }

        String type = f.getContentType().substring(6)

        String baseImageName = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        baseImageName = "user${user.id}"
// Saving image in a folder assets/channelImage/, in the web-app, with the name: baseImageName
        def downloadedFile = f  //.getFile( "product.baseImage" )
        String fileUploaded = fileUploadService.uploadFile( downloadedFile, "${baseImageName}.${type}", "assets/channelImage/" )
        if( fileUploaded ){
            user.avatarType = type
            user.save()
            message = "File Saved Successfully."
            redirect(action: 'show', params: [userId: userId])
        }
    }
```

my service action where I am trying to delete before save >>>

```
def String uploadFile( MultipartFile file, String name, String destinationDirectory ) {

    def serveletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
    def storagePath = serveletContext.getRealPath( destinationDirectory )       
    def storagePathDirectory = new File("${storagePath}/${name}").delete()

    // Store file

    if(!file.isEmpty()){
        file.transferTo( new File("${storagePath}/${name}") )
        println("Saved File: ${storagePath}/${name}")
        return "${storagePath}/${name}"
    }else{
        println "File: ${file.inspect()} was empty"
        return null
    }
}
```

my show method in controller >>>

```
def show = {
    Long uid = Long.parseLong(params.userId)
    def avatarUser = User.get(uid)
    String link = "user${avatarUser.id}.${avatarUser.avatarType}"
    [link:link]
}
```

my view page >>>

```
    <g:if test="${link}">
         <img src="${resource(dir: 'assets/channelImage', file: "${link}")}" />
</g:if>
```

Comment: Generally a good idea is to post what the error is you are coming across.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I am having this error >> "Destination file [E:\grailsTesting_2.1.0\web-app\assets\channelImage\user1.jpeg] already exists and could not be deleted"